# JAXB converting XSD to Java classes

Tags: java, xml, class, xsd, jaxb

When I run the following command:

```
xjc -b xmlSchema.xjb -d src -p com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.generatedxmlclasses xmlSchema.xsd
```

It creates Java classes however I've found that my root class does not have the correct name and does not have `@XmlRootElement` which declares it as a root element which means when I use the classes to generate XML it is not formed properly.

XSD Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Test" type="sel:TestType" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>

    <xs:complexType name="TestType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element type="sel:Option1" name="Option1" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
            <xs:element type="sel:Option2" name="Option2" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
            <xs:element type="sel:Option3" name="Option3" xmlns:sel="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testType xmlns="http://ibm.org/seleniumframework"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated classes correspond to complex types.  Anonymous complex types that are declared as part of global elements will get an `@XmlRootElement` annotation. Others will have a `@XmlElementDecl` annotation generated on the `ObjectFactory` class.  This is because there may be more than one global element that corresponds to the same complex type.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html